# Рефактор кода ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

вопрос следующий, никак в голову не может прийти идея, как отрефакторить данную часть кода,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]isDanger - это хук useState, если false, то просто применяем map, если true, то сначала filter, а потом map, хочется вот избежать повторное написание компонента AsteroidMainItem

Comment: добавь код вместо рисунка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну здесь все очень просто. Создайте отдельную переменную по которой будете рендерить

```js
const renderAsteroids = isDanger ? asteroids.filter(item => !!item.dangerous) : asteroids;

return (
   renderAsteroids.map(asteroid => <Link ... />)
)
```

Comment: Комментарий сверху помог, спасибо, Роман)